# Finitely connected orientable surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, riemann-surfaces, surfaces, conformal-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a finitely connected orientable complete Riemannian surface, that is, $M$ is homeomorphic to a compact orientable surface $\Sigma$ minus $k \geq 1$ points. Do you have references or a proof for the fact that $(M,g)$ is conformal to a compact orientable Riemann surface with $k \geq 1$ disks deleted?

This is part of an argument in the paper “ On complete minimal surfaces with finite Morse index in three manifolds”, by Fischer-Colbrie.

[image: argument]

Comment: Is this true in genus $0$? A sphere with a point removed is conformal to $\mathbb{C}$, whereas a sphere with a disk removed is conformal to the open unit disk $D$. Now, it seems to me that $\mathbb{C}$ and $D$ are $C^{\infty}$-equivalent but *not* conformally equivalent: in fact, every holomorphic map $f \colon \mathbb{C} \to D$ is bounded, hence constant by Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Francesco removing a closed disc with $r>0$ gives a different (not biholomorphic) Riemann surface  than removing a point. The later case is called removing a (closed) disc of radius 0 by Fischer-Colbrie. In fact, what the authors show in the proof at hand is that, under some natural geometric assumptions  on a minimal surface (e.g. completness +...), the underlying Riemann surface type is that of a punctured Riemann surface.

Comment: Ok. My question is how the author conclude from the finite connectivity of the surface that it must be conformal to a Riemann surface with some discs deleted.

Comment: Finite connectivity of the surface implies that the surface is diffeomorphic to a closed surface with finitely many points removed. Remove  small punctured discs around these points. These are topological annuli equipped with conformal structures. It is well-known (follows from Riemann mapping theorem) that the conformal types of annuli are $\mathbb C*$, $\mathbb D^*$ or $A_r=\{z\mid r^2<\bar z z<1\}$ for some $0<r<1.$ The first case does not occur in your situation. In the second case you glue in a point and in the third you glue a closed disc so that you obtain a closed RIemann surface.